# make list of dictionaries overwriting one key entry from a list using iterators

Tags: python, iterator, dictionary-comprehension

I have the horrible feeling this will be a duplicate, I tried my best to find the answer already.

I have a dictionary and a list, and I want to create a list of dictionaries, using the list to overwrite one of the key values, like this:

```
d={"a":1,"b":10}      
c=[3,4,5] 
arg=[]
for i in c:
    e=d.copy()
    e["a"]=i
    arg.append(e)
```

this gives the desired result

```
arg
[{'a': 3, 'b': 10}, {'a': 4, 'b': 10}, {'a': 5, 'b': 10}]
```

but the code is ugly, especially with the copy command, and instead of one list I have 4 or 5 in my real example which leads to a huge nested loop.  I feel sure there is a neater way with an iterator like

```
arg=[d *with* d[a]=i for i in c]
```

where I'm not sure what to put in the place of the "with".

Again, apologies if this is already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could do:

```
d={"a":1,"b":10}
c=[3,4,5]

res = [{ **d, "a" : ci } for ci in c]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'a': 3, 'b': 10}, {'a': 4, 'b': 10}, {'a': 5, 'b': 10}]
```

The part:

```
"a" : ci
```

rewrites the value at the key `"a"` and `**d` unpacks the dictionary.

Comment: I didn't know about the unpacking, thank you so much

Comment: BTW: in Python 3.9 there is new method `d | {"a": ci}` - `res = [ d | {"a": ci} for ci in c]`

Comment: @furas, nice, that's worth a full answer

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

```
arg=[d.copy() for i in range(len(c))]
for i in range(len(arg)):
    arg[i]['a']=c[i]
```

This code first creates a list of dictionaries with the length of c and then updates 'a' for each dictionary, with the respective itme of c

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using a dictionary comprehension within a list comprehension, checking for key == 'a':

```
d = {"a":1,"b":10}
c = [3,4,5]
l = [{k: num if k == 'a' else v for k,v in d.items()} for num in c]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.9 there is new method to create new dictionary with updated values and keep old dictionary without updates - using operator `|`

```
new_dict = old_dict | dict_with_updates
```

With list comprehension it will be

```
arg = [ d | {"a": i} for i in c]
```

Full example

```
d = {"a": 1, "b": 10}
c = [3, 4, 5]

arg = [ d | {"a": i} for i in c]

print(arg)
```

---

BTW: There is also `|=` to update existing dictionary

```
old_dict |= dict_with_updates
```

---

Doc: [What’s New In Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#dictionary-merge-update-operators)

Comment: that's brilliant, will try it out as soon as our system gets updated from 3.6